# How can I have a maximum speed for my objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have an array that are considered enemies. Their base speed is 2 (enemyBaseSpeed). Depending on what level the user on, the speed increases each time and is multiplied by (speedLevelInc) which is .5. The equation is as follows:

```
tempEnemy.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
```

I want to give the enemies a maximum speed once they reach a specific level, let's say level 5. When they reach level 5, I want them to run on a constant max speed of let's say 6. Even if they do get to level 6,7,8... I want all of them to run on the max speed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cap the value after assigning the speed.

```
tempEnemy.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
if (tempEnemy.speed > MAX_SPEED) {
    tempEnemy.speed = MAX_SPEED;
}
```

It will be better to use a setter instead of making `speed` a public property. For example, if you have a `Enemy` class then:

```
private var _speed:Number;
private const MAX_SPEED:Number = 4; // change this as needed

public function set speed(value:Number):void {
    _speed = value;
    if (_speed > MAX_SPEED) {
        _speed = MAX_SPEED;
    }
}

public function get speed():Number {
    return _speed;
}

// from other place, value will be capped to MAX_SPEED
tempEnemy.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
```